# Why it takes two file selections for field to populate?

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing strange problem with React I never faced before.
For some reason I have to select file to upload twice for it to get populated
into state:

```
  const [passportFile, setPassportFile] = useState();
  const [firstSelfieFile, setFirstSelfieFile] = useState();
  const [secondSelfieFile, setSecondSelfieFile] = useState();
  const [thirdSelfieFile, setThirdSelfieFile] = useState();


  const handlePassportUpload = e => {
    setPassportFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setPassportPresent(true);
    console.log(passportFile);
  };

  const handleSelfieUpload = e => {
    if (e.target.name === "first_selfie") {
      setFirstSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
      setFirstSelfiePresent(true);
      console.log(firstSelfieFile);
    } else if (e.target.name === "second_selfie") {
      setSecondSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
      setSecondSelfiePresent(true);
    } else if (e.target.name === "third_selfie") {
      setThirdSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
      setThirdSelfiePresent(true);
    }
  };

return (

 <div className="file">
      <label className="file-label">
        <input
          onChange={handlePassportUpload}
          className="file-input is-rounded"
          type="file"
          name="passport_photo"
        />
        <span className="file-cta">
          <span className="file-icon">
            <i className="fas fa-upload" />
          </span>
          <span className="file-label">Upload Passport Photo</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br />
        <div className="file">
          <label className="file-label">
            <input
              onChange={handleSelfieUpload}
              className="file-input"
              type="file"
              name="first_selfie"
            />
            <span className="file-cta">
              <span className="file-icon">
                <i className="fas fa-upload" />
              </span>
              <span className="file-label">Upload First Selfie</span>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
)
```

Is there any reason why I get "undefined" the first time around and then the file gets uploaded ? I've got pretty much the same code for uploading files in another React project and it worked just fine. I compared the code and couldn't see why the code behaves differently this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is setPassportFile (basically setting anything in useState hook) is **asynchronous**. **You're logging the state immediately after setting it**. but it is asynchronous, so the handlePassportUpload and handleSelfieUpload functions will execute then the state will update.

So, try to console.log() outside these functions. It'll work.

For the second part about it being undefined, it is because you're not initializing the state with anything.

what you're doing -:

```
const [passportFile, setPassportFile] = useState();
```

what you should do -:

```
const [passportFile, setPassportFile] = useState("");
```

This applies to all state initialization.

Your code should look like this -:

```
const [passportFile, setPassportFile] = useState("");
const [firstSelfieFile, setFirstSelfieFile] = useState("");
const [secondSelfieFile, setSecondSelfieFile] = useState("");
const [thirdSelfieFile, setThirdSelfieFile] = useState("");

console.log(passportFile);
console.log(firstSelfieFile);

const handlePassportUpload = (e) => {
  setPassportFile(e.target.files[0]);
  setPassportPresent(true);
};

const handleSelfieUpload = (e) => {
  if (e.target.name === "first_selfie") {
    setFirstSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFirstSelfiePresent(true);
  } else if (e.target.name === "second_selfie") {
    setSecondSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setSecondSelfiePresent(true);
  } else if (e.target.name === "third_selfie") {
    setThirdSelfieFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setThirdSelfiePresent(true);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    <div className="file">
      <label className="file-label">
        <input
          onChange={handlePassportUpload}
          className="file-input is-rounded"
          type="file"
          name="passport_photo"
        />
        <span className="file-cta">
          <span className="file-icon">
            <i className="fas fa-upload" />
          </span>
          <span className="file-label">Upload Passport Photo</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div className="file">
      <label className="file-label">
        <input
          onChange={handleSelfieUpload}
          className="file-input"
          type="file"
          name="first_selfie"
        />
        <span className="file-cta">
          <span className="file-icon">
            <i className="fas fa-upload" />
          </span>
          <span className="file-label">Upload First Selfie</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </>
);
```